Does c# use UTF-8 or UTF-16 for strings?
To be more precise, the latest version of c# (c# 12 (.NET 8.0)), does it use UTF-8 or UTF-16 for strings?
I am confused because:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding-introduction

A string is logically a sequence of 16-bit values, each of which is an instance of the char struct.

And here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/5.0/icu-globalization-api

.NET 5 and later versions use International Components for Unicode (ICU) libraries for globalization functionality when running on Windows 10 May 2019 Update or later.

And what if run on Linux? Do I have to provide the ICU lib?
Or is the statement, c# still uses 16-bit values and deletes the zeros for all latin languages and maps this than to the ICU?

In C#, strings are stored internally as UTF-16 encoded. This means that each character in a string occupies 16 bits of memory. String always contains Unicode (or more precisely, UTF-16).

Unless the "character" is non-BMP (> U+FFFF) and uses UTF-16 surrogates, then it uses 32 bits (4 bytes) of memory, or the single visual "character" is a grapheme of multiple code points.

Yes, you are correct.

@MarkTolonen That's still UTF-16. Each char is actually a codepoint, not a character.

@Charlieface I know what a code point is.  That's why "character" is in quotes.  I'm correcting the sentence that says "each character in a string occupies 16 bits of memory".  The "character" (a single code point) takes 4 bytes (2 UTF-16 code units).  The ‍‍‍ "character" (7 code points) takes up 14 bytes (7 UTF-16 code units).

Oops, correction, the ‍‍‍ "character" (7 code points) takes up 22 bytes (11 UTF-16 code units).  4 of those code points are non-BMP.

It appears to be UTF16:

Today there is no efficient syntax for doing this as C# represents all
strings using UTF16 encoding.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/utf8-string-literals
